# Converting data type in excel using formulas and without using macros/vba

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use the following array formula:

```
 =SUM(IF(MONTH(M8:M10)=5,1,0) * IF(B6:B8="C",1,0) * IF(C6:C8="XX",1,0))
```

However, I keep getting the error: "A value used in this formula is of the wrong data type". I know it comes from the M8-M10 columns being in the 'general' format and same with B6-B8 and C6-C8. I can't simply change the data type of these columns from the excel header tab because I have certain restrictions.

How can I convert the data type IN the actual formula? Is there a function for this? Is there something along the lines of CONVERTtoNummber() in Excel?

***EDIT:*** Here is what the data looks like (the columns are going from left to right just as in the formula)

```
    Date             Product Type        Supplier
   12-May-2015           C                XX
   23-Sep-2015           B                XK
   12-May 2015           C                XA
```

Comment: what do the values in M8:M10 look like? can you post a screenshot of the data?

Comment: You can use `Text([the data], "#,#00.0")`, but I'm not sure that'll work.  Can you post a screenshot (or copy/pasted table) of your data?

Comment: Should you be using an array formula??

Comment: Try `MONTH(DATEVALUE(M8:M10))`

Comment: You could also try performing some sort of inconsequential mathematical operation on the cells in question, such as multiplying by one.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman just posted the values

Comment: @BruceWayne just posted the values

Comment: the formula worked for me as is, but there is no way for me to tell how your data comes into your spreadsheet - I set mine as text to try to mimic. did you try @Kyle suggestion for wrapping `DATEVALUE` around the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce this error is if I don't array enter the formula. Make sure your confirm your formula by clicking in the formula bar and pressing ctrl+shift+enter. Or try this alternative that does not need to be array-entered:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(M8:M10)=5),--(B6:B8="C"),--(C6:C8="XX"))
```

Comment: If I use my original formula and put an array it works. However, if I use an array bu remove the last if statement, I get the same error

Comment: @noname738 Like `=SUM(IF(MONTH(M8:M10)=5,1,0) * IF(B6:B8="C",1,0))`? That formula is valid, you should not get an error. Note: you can tell if a formula is array-entered because it will be surrounded in curly braces, like `{=SUM(IF(...))}` in the formula bar. But do not add the curly braces yourself.